# django, datetime into template could not parse

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates

I get this error Could not parse the remainder: '(datetime.datetime.now()' from '(datetime.datetime.now()'

problematic code

```
{% if pr.update_news != "" and (datetime.datetime.now() - pr.update_date).days < 10 %}
```

Seems like not understand datetime. 
pr.update_date its a Date field into DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django template language is limited, you can't embed arbitrary Python like you have done.

You can create a model method that contains the logic. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

class PR(models.Model):
    ...
    def has_recent_news(self):
        return self.update_news and (datetime.now() - self.update_date).days < 10
```

Then in your template, use the method:

```
{% if pr.has_recent_news %}
```

Note you don't do `pr.has_recent_news()` in the template. You do `pr.has_recent_news`, and Django calls the method automatically.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it before your post but same way... remembered that the "Writing your first Django app" tutorial has something like this